# save email address from contact form in datalayer

Tags: javascript, grav, data-layers

I have a form on my website and when a customer fills it out he gets to a thank-you page. Now I would like that the email address from the form is pushed dynamically in the datalayer on the thank-you page. Does anyone have an idea how I can implement that in my code?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "datalayer"?

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ form.value.something }}
```

In template or page-content, where `something` is your field-name in form